# Differences in using array in main program or in functions sub-routines

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I'v got some question about using array pointers in program. 
When I use some array name (which is a const pointer to first array element)

```
char charTab[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWXYZ";    /* Basic data buffer */

char *charPtr = charTab;                        /* Assign */
charPtr += 3;                                   /* It's ok, now we point 4th element */
charTab += 3;                                   /* No, the lvalue required for '+' operand */
```

But when I create let's say the following function:

```
void CharTabMove(char *tabToMove, int noToMove);
```

With definition

```
void CharTabMove(char *tabToMove, int noToMove)
{
    printf("-------IN FUNCTION---------\n");
    printf("It's pointing to %c\n", *tabToMove);
    tabToMove += noToMove;
    printf("Now it's pointing to %c\n", *tabToMove);
    printf("-------LEAVING FUNCTION---------\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

The function is allow to move this pointer along the array with no problem. Sure, after leaving the function the pointer will be still pointing to first element of charTab, but why the function is allowed to move the constant pointer?
Thanks in advice for response, I'm trying to explain that to my 11 yo nephew :)

#### ---EDIT after couple of years ---

Ok, time pass and now I see why my question was not formulated accurately. I misguided you by using term `const pointer` referring to array name before and after passing it function. To rephrase, question boils down to:

Why this is not allowed:

```
char charTab[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWXYZ";    /* Basic data buffer */
charTab += 3;                                   /* No, the lvalue required for '+' operand */
```

While this is allowed:

```
char charTab[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUWXYZ";    /* Basic data buffer */
void CharTabMove(char *tabToMove, int noToMove)
{
    tabToMove += noToMove;
}
CharTabMove(charTab)
```

And the answer is as I gathered and refined all of your answers, `charTab` acts **almost** like constant pointer to first element of array, but essentially is not an lvalue or a pointer statement, so arthmetic operations are not allowed. When passing it to function, this **almost** like constant pointer to first array element will be casted and passed by value as regular pointer, so operations can be executed on it.

Comment: What do you mean, the constant pointer? `tabToMove` is `char*` - nary a `const` in sight. On the other hand, `charTab` is convertible to `char* const`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: often in school they teach the misguided idea that an array is a constant pointer to its content (constant in the fact that the pointer cannot be changed, i.e. something like `char * const`).

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Yes, and? Isn't that precisely my point? `charTab` is an array, and can be thought of as a const pointer to its content. `tabToMove` is not an array, and is not const. If that's what one (fairly reasonably) believes, why would one find the observed behavior surprising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one difference between an array name and a pointer that must be kept in mind. A pointer is a variable, so `pa=a` and `pa++` are legal. But an array name is not a
variable; constructions like `a=pa` and `a++` are illegal. here `pa` is pointer.

`charPtr += 3;` ==> this is allowed because this is pointer , pointer arithmetic is allowed and you can change the location of pointer.

`charTab += 3;` ==> here this is illegal.you should not change the position of array.

and

`tabToMove` ==> is  character pointer.you can modify it.

Answer (score 1):

`charTab` is an array; `charPtr` and `tabToMove` are pointers. If you were able to change `charTab` you'd effectively lose track of where the beginning of the array is. If you change `charPtr` or `tabToMove` you don't have the same problem -- they're copies of the pointer to the beginning of the array.

> but why the function is allowed to move the constant pointer?

It's not a constant pointer -- you've declared it as `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the name of the array is not a constant pointer, it is just name of the array; the point is that an array in almost any context *decays* to a pointer to the first element of the array.

The array by itself cannot be incremented, but, once it decays to a pointer to the first element and *is assigned to some pointer variable*, it can be incremented (the second step is fundamental, since, to increment something, you must have an lvalue).

Now, functions cannot directly receive arrays as parameters (even if you write an array in the function signature it's implicitly interpreted as a pointer), so, when you pass an array to a function it surely decays to a pointer to its first element, and it's used to initialize the parameter of the function, which then can be incremented as you wish: in facts, the *parameter* `tabToMove` is just a local variable of type `char *` which is initialized with the passed *argument*, i.e. the pointer to the first element of the array.

In other words, if you write

```
char foo[]="asdasdas";
CharTabMove(foo, 5);
```

is like you were doing

```
char foo[]="asdasdas";
char *tabToMove=foo;
int noToMove=5;
CharTabMove(tabToMove, noToMove);
```

Comment: "The array by itself cannot be incremented, but, once it decays to a pointer to the first element and is assigned to some pointer variable, it can be incremented" This is perhaps worded a bit loosely. One can certainly write `charTab + 3`; here, an array decays to a pointer, which is then incremented, without anything being assigned to anything else. What one can't do is assign the result back to `charTab`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: *"here, an array decays to a pointer, which is then incremented"* -- Not correct.  An array decays to a pointer, which then is added together with an integer creating a completely separate pointer.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: the point is that you are not incrementing `charTab`, you are incrementing the resulting pointer in an expression; the idea there was that you can't do `+=` over `charTab`. Still, I agree it may be worded better.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a const pointer.

Actually, in the function, you just change a non-const pointer which just has the same value(passed by value when calling function) of your const point.